# Why does the program stop if I'm using strcpy() on two strings with the exact same size in C?

Tags: c, string, windows, codeblocks, string.h

I use CodeBlocks for Windows as my IDE. In this program, I am trying to copy two different strings (string[8][0] with string[9][0]), and I can't, even though they have the exact same length. I don't understand why the program isn't working because, when I used two different strings with the same length in an exercise the program, worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* string[10][10];
    int i;
    string[8][0] = "ooo";
    string[9][0] = "uuu";
    puts(string[8][0]);
    puts(string[9][0]);
    printf("%d %d", strlen(string[8][0]), strlen(string[9][0]));//This line is just to make sure that both strings have the same lenght
    strcpy(string[8][0], string[9][0]);//I want to copy the content of the string "string[9][0]" to the string "string[8][0]" and replace what was on that string
    puts(string[8][0]);
    puts(string[9][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should happen, when we try to modify a string constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211884/what-should-happen-when-we-try-to-modify-a-string-constant)

Comment: regarding `string[8][0] = "ooo";` and simolar statements:  the code is trying to force a string into a single char,   Suggest: `strcpy( string[8], "ooo" );

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is *undefined behaviour*<sup>1</sup>. Why? Because the line `string[8][0] = "ooo";` assigns, to the pointer at `string[8][0]`, the address of a **constant** string literal. Then, when you later call `strcpy(string[8][0], string[9][0]);`, you are trying to *write* to that constant data.

A 'quick fix' to make your program work is to copy the string literal into a non-constant char array, like so:

```c
int main()
{
    char* string[10][10];
    int i;
    //    string[8][0] = "ooo";
    char buffer[4] = "ooo"; // This line COPIES the literal into the non-const array
    string[8][0] = buffer;  // ... and here we give the pointer that array's address
    string[9][0] = "uuu";
    puts(string[8][0]);
    puts(string[9][0]); // Note, I've added a newline below to make the output tidier!
    printf("%d %d\n", strlen(string[8][0]), strlen(string[9][0]));//This line is just to make sure that both strings have the same lenght
    strcpy(string[8][0], string[9][0]);//I want to copy the content of the string "string[9][0]" to the string "string[8][0]" and replace what was on that string
    puts(string[8][0]);
    puts(string[9][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> The undefined behaviour can cause any number of things to happen! On some platforms, the program may silently 'ignore' your attempt to overwrite the constant data; on my platform, the program crashes (as it appears to on yours).

Comment: Thanks for the response! This programm was only an example, and in my actual programm the content of the array string[8][0] is random, and that's why I can't just use the char buffer with always the same value. Is there another way to fix this problem?

Comment: The only thing you have to ensure is any pointer passed as the *first* argument to the `strcpy` function (that is, the *destination* string) does not point to a constant (literal) string. How to check for (or prevent) this in your real-world program depends on many factors; maybe you need to re-think your design?

Comment: How do I acess a specific char of the string[9][0]? I want to acess only the first 'u' for example.

Answer (score 0):

regarding

```
string[8][0] = "ooo";
```

and similar statements:

the code is copying a point to read-only memory

And remember that read-only memory cannot be changed by the program.

Suggest modifying the code so the string(s) are actually placed in the array, similar to.

```
char string[10][10];
...
strcpy( string[0], "ooo" );
```

regarding:

```
printf("%d %d\n", strlen(string[8][0]), strlen(string[9][0]));
```

the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int` so the output format conversion' specifiers should be `%zu` not `%d`

If you compiler did not warn you about the problems in the code, then enable the warnings then fix those warnings.

For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Note the other compilers use different options to produce the same results